# RestSharp Call to IBM Watson, Error

Tags: c#, restsharp, watson

I am hoping someone can help me, I am using RESTSHARP to post a file to IBM's WATSON's Document Conversion API, my code is below, everytime I run this I just get...

{\n  \"code\" : 400,\n  \"error\" : \"Media type not provided\"\n}

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            string resume = dr["file"].ToString();
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(resume);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(resume);

            string file = baseDir + resume;

            var client = new RestClient("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion/api/v1/convert_document?version=2015-12-15")
            {
                Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
            };

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            string json = "{ \"conversion_target\" : \"normalized_text\" }";
            request.AddParameter("config", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.AddFile(fileName, file);

            var response = client.Execute(request);

        }
```

Comment: What kind of file are you posting? Try to specify the MIME Type explicitly if it's not one of those that are listed in the docs: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/document-conversion/api/v1/#convert-document

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its a PDF, I have tried uploading the MIME type and it makes no difference, even though the error says 'Media type not provided' I think this is just a generic error as error code 400 means "400 Bad Request The input document failed to convert, or your request was malformed."

Comment: I have used the Watson service back in school once, and all I recall about it is that you should explicitly set everything. So you should try to set the MIME type and outputs in your request. Also, try to set an Accept header to application/json.

Comment: no luck im afraid